# How to use a preference for only one website when there is multisite functionality magento 2?

Tags: magento2.2, multi-website, preference

I have created a preference to override the functionality of customer save. But the I need to use the core customer save functionality for 1 website and  my preference functionality for another website.
 So how can I implement this?

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You likely do not need a preference here and instead you very likely can achieve your changes via a plugin on the save method.

In the plugin code itself you can add a check for the website to either execute the changes or keep it as is.

Answer (score 0):

There are not any native functionality to the differentiate `preference` for multiple websites or stores.

You can make a condition for the current store or website by `Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface` in the overridden method.

**Example:**

```
public function myFunction($item)
{
    if($this->_storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId() == '1') {
        //Do your customisation 
    } else {
        //Return main function
        return parent::myFunction($item);
    }
}
```